# Glitches on streamed videos

Tags: nvidia, videos, bumblebee

I have been experiencing constant glitch from any stream source available, even from netflix and youtube.

Basically it looks like there are parts of two frames at same time on the screen. I see 90% of a frame and a square or rectangle of other frame overlapping it. It happens all the time sometimes it looks likes the frame still rendering when the next one is already been showed.

Pantheon also looks weird with its animations.

I have tried out Linux Mint and it has the same symptom, but I have also tried Manjaro, which has no issue.

I have tried using the drivers that comes with the distro and also tried install the suggested NVIDIA drivers.

```
Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
8,1 GB memory
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit) from the AppCenter

Comment: Just for the sake of it, would you be willing to try Chromium (from the AppCenter) to see if the issue replicates itself? Also, does this happen if you use the Epiphany browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extened research and trials I managed to find a almost perfect fix.

Edit:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add:

```
 Option      "TearFree" "true"
```

It will looks like something like this:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: You might want to add how the solution helped fixing your problem, that may help other people with similar issues.